# RedirectMatch 301s same page URL to multiple TLDs

Tags: php, .htaccess, magento, redirect, http-status-code-301

We're working on a magento store at the moment where multiple 301 redirects have previously been implemented. The original .htaccess file has lots of rules in such as the following:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/original-page.html http://www.yourdomain.co.uk/our-new-directory/new-page.html
RedirectMatch 301 ^/original-page2.html http://www.yourdomain.co.uk/our-new-directory/new-page2.html 
RedirectMatch 301 ^/original-page3.html http://www.yourdomain.co.uk/our-new-directory/new-page3.html
```

The website has now had a new TLD setup, so if you visit http://www.yourdomain.de/original-page.html, you're getting redirected to http://www.yourdomain.co.uk/our-new-directory/new-page.html.

What I want to do is have it so that we have the following:

Someone types in:

```
http://www.yourdomain.co.uk/original-page.html and gets redirected to http://www.yourdomain.co.uk/our-new-directory/new-page.html
```

AND

```
http://www.yourdomain.de/original-page.html and gets redirected to http://www.yourdomain.de/our-new-directory/new-page.html
```

Essentially, the redirect should take into account the TLD that the user is on. The main reason for this is that many pages on the website have URLs where they've been 301 redirected.

Any assistance on this would be brilliant.

Kind regards,
Lewis

Answer (score 0):

Place this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.yourdomain\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^original-page\.html$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/our-new-directory/new-page.html [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this didn't work. I'm not sure if something else in the Magento .htaccess file was stopping it working but the only types of redirects we've got working with Magento are Redirect Match 301s.

Comment: Which URL did you use to test these rules?

Comment: Also make sure this rule is **before all other rules** you already have.

Answer (score 0):

You can just remove the hostname part of your redirects:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/original-page.html /our-new-directory/new-page.html
RedirectMatch 301 ^/original-page2.html /our-new-directory/new-page2.html 
RedirectMatch 301 ^/original-page3.html /our-new-directory/new-page3.html
```